# Working with nil in Swift

Tags: swift, null, unwrap

If my server side after mapping JSON, is expecting the null values as default (written in Java), is it somehow possible to work with nil values in Swift, and map them and send them as it is without unwrapping?

I made my variables as Optionals, because maybe it will has value in some point, maybe it will not. But i'm forced to unwrap it, even if i want to send a nil value.

This is my code:

```
private var _username: String?

var username: String{
    get{

        return self._username

    }set(username){

        self._username = username
    }
}
```

And if i try with Optional Chaining, it force me to do this on 6th line:

```
return (self._username?)!
```

but then i get this kind of error: " '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript"

Is there any way to work with nil in Swift, or i have to change default values on backend?

Comment: Your private var is an optional; is there any reason the public variable is not optional?

Comment: And what's the purpose of public variables with backing private variables? That's not Swift style

Comment: Remove the ? The variable _username is already an optional, simply use ! to force unwrap it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass them "as is" because your server has no idea what nil in Swift is. You can, however, pass either a string that means nil to you or the JSON `null` value.

This is a good time to use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

```
private var _username: String?

var username: String{
    get{

        // This will return the username if it is .Some or "null" if it is .None
        return self._username ?? "null"
        // Note that when you create the JSON object there is a difference between
        // "null" which is a string and null which is the JSON equivalent to nil.

    } set(username) {

        self._username = username
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
var username: String?
```

as:

```
private var _username: String?

var username: String? {
    get{
        return self._username
    }set(username){
        self._username = username
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with a computed variable at all if you delegate all work to the private variable?